# Jquery Toggle: closing a toggle element

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, slidetoggle

I have this query which works fine except that when I click on a toggle item that is already open, it slides up but then it slides down right away. You can see it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RTGEt/1/).

The query is :

```
$(".faqtopics").click(function(event) {
    $("div.faqtext").slideUp(400);
    $(this).next("div.faqtext").slideToggle();
});
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [**`.stop()`**](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

> Description: Stop the currently-running animation on the matched elements.

*Code*

```
$(".faqtopics").click(function(event) {
    $("div.faqtext").stop(true).slideUp(400);
    $(this).next("div.faqtext").stop(true).slideToggle();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/UwGs7/)

Comment: Sorry Satpal, it's working good on jsfiddle but not on my website! Do you have an idea why?

Comment: @Arone, Are you getting any error in browser console?

Comment: no, everything is fine on my website except that I can'y click anymore on the toggle

Comment: Sorry it's working now! I forgot to use the var $j = jQuery.noConflict(); Thanks a lot for your help!